# Creating a nginx virtual host configuration file

Tags: nginx

I have gone through several nginx tutorials but none of them explains the virtual host configuration file extension.

I have looked at the `default` file from this location on ubuntu

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available#
```

But i cant seem to understand the extension of the file. is it a .conf file?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx read all files from this directory, on my servers filename equals domain:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available:
     example.com
     subpage.example.com
```

You don't need any specific file extension. I hope I dispelled your doubts.